# Why Eclipse clean after mvn clean install

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a interesting observation at my new job at a Major Silicon Valley Company.

This is a mvn/java project.
I am being told to do command-line "mvn clean install" and then go to Eclipse and select Project & then do "Clean" Build.

I am confused as the difference between "mvn clean install" & Eclipse "Clean", I thought since it's the same pom.xml the outcome should be the same. Interstingly my code changes to java classes do not show till I have done both. I was expecting to see changes after command-line "mvn clean install"

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has own project structure and build routines.
Maven has own project lifecycle.

Maven integrates into Eclipse with m2e plugin. It is some kind of art to relate Maven and Eclipse stages one to one.

Therefore it very easy to fall into situation when some Eclipse command did not doing all what Maven needs and vice versa, just because m2e can not relate all features of Eclipse and Maven 1 to 1.

Simplest advice is to use Eclipse IDE support for code navigation and editing, but use Maven to clean, compile, package and so on. In this case Eclipse's 'Runtime configurations' very helpfull in configuring and executing Maven's commands.

Use 'Alt+F5' to sync project state.